# Sub root nodes deleting after login again in Firebase? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I have "likes" root node to hold many post id for every users. But after login with facebook, everytime likes node deleting/updating from users. Is there a problem? How Can I prevent this case and update except "likes" root node?

```
               let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

                DataService.ds.REF_BASE.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: {
                    error, authData in


                    if error != nil {
                        print("Login failed. \(error)")
                    }
                    else {

                        print("Successfully logged in with facebook. \(accessToken)")
                        print("Logged in! \(authData)")

                        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"
                        let stringDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
                        print("createdAt: " + stringDate)

                        let user =
                        ["id": authData.providerData["id"] as! String,
                         "accessToken": authData.providerData["accessToken"] as! String,
                         "provider": authData.provider!,
                         "displayName": authData.providerData["displayName"] as! String,
                         "email": authData.providerData["email"] as! String,
                         "profileImageURL": authData.providerData["profileImageURL"] as! String,
                         "token": authData.token as String,
                         "createdAt": stringDate]

                        DataService.ds.createFirebaseUser(authData.uid, user: user)


                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_LOGGED_IN, sender: nil)

                    }


                })
```

In addition my createFirebaseUser function in DataService class.

```
func createFirebaseUser(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    REF_USERS.childByAppendingPath(uid).setValue(user)
}
```

Comment: I have solved it and published below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by myself, learned that I need to do **updateChildValues()** after creating account for first time. Sharing this scope maybe help others who encounter with same problem.

[image]